# ¿Cómo comparo un decimal y un caracter en emu8086?

Tags: programación-bajo-nivel, ensamblador

Tengo una duda con un ejercicio que estoy intentando resolver, lo adjunto para que me entiendan mejor:

> Escriba un programa en lenguaje ensamblador que dada una secuencia de caracteres ASCII terminada con '$' obtenga en el registro AX la cantidad de dígitos decimales que aparecen en la secuencia, y en CX la cantidad total de caracteres sin contar el carácter '$'

Bueno, por el momento puedo recorrer la cadena, pero no sé cómo diferenciar decimales de caracteres. No pido que me resuelvan el ejercicio solo la instrucción que tengo que utilizar, esto es lo que voy haciendo por ahora:

```
org 100h
jmp INICIO
texto dw "123asd$" 

INICIO:
mov bx, offset texto
mov ax,0
mov cx,0

ciclo:
cmp [bx],'$'

jne contar
je fin

contar:
inc bx
inc cx 
jmp ciclo

fin:
ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los dígitos decimales no son más que un carácter más a la hora de representarlos.

Es decir, para un ordenador, imprimir por pantalla un '1' o un 'A' es lo mismo.

Si te piden que cuentes los dígitos decimales, te están pidiendo que cuentes cuantos caracteres tienen la característica de ser la representación de un número.

Si pillas una tabla ASCII (http://www.elcodigoascii.com.ar/ por ejemplo)  verás que el número '0' tiene el valor 48, el '1' tiene el valor 49 .... , el '9' tiene el valor 57. Resumiendo, un carácter es la representación de un número decimal si su valor está entre 48 y 57 ambos inclusive.

Tal como tienes montado el código con un par de compares lo tendrás fácil para implementarlo. Si te surgieran dudas, dilo.

Nos vemos

Comment: Gracias voy a ver si me sale

Comment: Recuerda que si la respuesta te ha sido util marcarla como respuesta correcta

Answer (score 0):

hace tiempo que no toco emu , pero creo que sería así, no tengo ahora los medios para comprobarlo(el compilador y s.o), asi que es mas o menos la idea.

```
org 100h
jmp INICIO
texto dw "123asd$" 

INICIO:
mov bx, offset texto
mov ax,0
mov cx,0

ciclo:
cmp [bx],'$'

jne contar
je fin

contar:
cmp [bx],'0'
jge menor
inc cx
inc bx
jmp ciclo

menor:
    cmp [bx] ,'9'
    jle incrementar 
incrementar:
    inc ax

fin:
ret
```

Comment: No me hagas mucho caso, pero.... ese jle incrementar y justo debajo el tag de incrementar: no tiene mucho sentido no? Salga lo que salga de la comparación seguirá por ahi